# Why nested loop block appear in acutal exection plan?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, indexing

I work on a testing social website. I was asked to create index for the query that get the pages that a user follows.I am new to indexes so I created three tables and filled them with 4500000 records for testing. The three tables are the same except for the primary key and indexes. The tables is shown in the image :

[image]

I use the same query for the three tables to get the pages that a user follows. The query is :

```
Select top 10 PageID from UserFollowPages where UserID='something' order by ID
```

The first table has a unique clustered index made of PageID and UserID.

The Second table has a unique non-clustered index made of PageID and UserID columns. The second table has also clustered index made of ID column.

The third table has non-clustered index made of UserID only. It also has a clustered index made of ID.

I execute the query for the three tables and include the actual execution plan. The result for the three tables is shown in the images.

The result for first query from the first table :
[image: Actual execution plan]

The result for the second query from the second table :
[image: Actual execution plan]

The result for the third query for the third table :
[image: Actual execution plan]

I have two question :

1. Why there is a nested loops (inner join) block that is shown in the actual execution plan for the third query ?
2. Which one of the three indexes should I use , knowing that the three queries take almost the same time to execute (almost 0.5 second)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Nested loop

It's quite simple. You have an Non-Clustered Index (NCI) on the UserId and a Clustered on the ID itself.

SQL Server uses the NCI to filter your rows according to your `WHERE`-clause. After that, the Index returns all needed pages and rows. SQL Server will use now those informations to make a Clustered Lookup in the Clustered Index to retrieve all other needed informations (all other columns). It would disappear if you just want to query the `UserID` itself.

```
Select UserID from UserFollowPages where UserID='something'
```

Just because all information is contained in one index. You can avoid this (if it is really necessary to avoid it) by using included columns using `INCLUDE(pageId, Id)` on the NCI.

## 2. Which one to use

Due to the fact that all are very small, it's not quite easy to determine. It depends on the way you query the tables. I need more information for this.

In fact you should evaluate, how much is your table written, how often is it queried. If your table is written 1 time and read 1 million times, it is good to have some more indices for all needed use-cases.
If your table is 100 times written and 10 times read, I would recommend to ignore the indices as they just waste your power and disc space (in most cases in such a situation).

Given the case you always query the table using the UserID, I would suggest that you should use a construct like in your third table. An clustered index on the `ID` (as it is sequential) and a NCI over `UserId` including `PageId`.

Comment: Sorry was too fast in the submit. ;-) Wanted you to give something to read till I'm writing the second part. It's already submitted

Comment: For your suggestion (An clustered index on the ID (as it is sequential) and a NCI over UserId including PageId.) do you mean including PageID as included column ?

Comment: Not really. Well it depends on your use case. Do you really order it based on the ID? If this is your normal use case, forget the include, just make the Clustered lookup. If you just want the pageID based on the UserId, then think about the include.

Comment: Thanks hopefully this describes everything you need for your question. :-)

Comment: Sorry, but I forget to ask about the first construct. Before your answer I was thinking it is the good one. What do you think about it ?

Comment: It depends. If you query it using the UserID then I would suggest to have a Clustered index on (UserId, PageId). If it's (PageId, UserId) it won't benefit from it. Another thing can be index fragmentation / reorganization. The combination of PageId/UserID may cause some reorganisations. Giving the example, you have 20 pageId's for one user, followed by another user (in this order). If you add a new pageId to the first user, it may cause a reorganization as the other rows need to moved back to get some space for the new row in between.